# fetchArray() not working in SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm working with SQLite on my webserver and have had no problems until now.

```
        $sql = "SELECT * from TeammateCurrent;";
        $ret = $db->query($sql);

        if($ret != false) {

            while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
                $uniqueid = $row['uniqueID'];

                $name = $row['Name'];
                $lineID = $row['LineID'];
                $job = $row['Job'];
                $sunday = $row['Sunday'];
                $monday = $row['Monday'];
                $tuesday = $row['Tuesday'];
                $wednesday = $row['Wednesday'];
                $thursday = $row['Thursday'];
                $friday = $row['Friday'];
                $saturday = $row['Saturday'];
                //echo $name."<br>".$lineID."<br>".$job."<br>".$sunday."<br>".$monday."<br>".$tuesday."<br>".$wednesday."<br>".$thursday."<br>".$friday."<br>".$saturday."<br><br>";

                $sql = "INSERT INTO TeammateHistory (uniqueID, Name,LineID,Job,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday)
                    VALUES (NULL, '$name','$lineID','$job','$sunday','$monday','$tuesday','$wednesday','$thursday','$friday','$saturday');";

                $ret = $db->exec($sql);
                if(!$ret){
                    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
                } else {

                }

                $sql2 = "UPDATE TeammateCurrent set Sunday='$day0', Monday='$day1', Tuesday='$day2', Wednesday='$day3', Thursday='$day4', Friday='$day5', Saturday='$day6' where uniqueID='$uniqueid';";

                $ret = $db->exec($sql2);
                if(!$ret){
                    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
                } else {

                }
            }

        } else {
            echo "Query not successful";
        }
```

When the code above executes, I get the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on a non-object in /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx.com/trg/rc2/db/startNewWeek.php on line 39`

I've ran code just like this on other pages and they work fine, I'm at a total loss here.

My tables:

[image]

Comment: If you run the `select` in the sqlite command line does it work?

Comment: @Apokryfos I'm not sure how to do that, is it possible on a remote server?

Comment: @Saty that is part of the documentation @ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm I did try however, and did not work still.

Comment: If the remote server allows SSH connections and has the sqlite3 CLI (or similar) installed you can just remote in and do something like : `sqlite3 dbname.db "query"`

Comment: @apokryfos I don't think I have access to ssh in my current project

Comment: Also, it's ALWAYS good practice to check whether the query was successful (in this case `$ret != false`) before attempting to use it. If the query fails, there may be an error message in the SQL client you can check.

Comment: @apokryfos check out my updated code. It does NOT echo the fail statement.

Comment: `If I uncomment out the echo'd string in my while statement, it appears it gets through a single iteration and then throws the error mentioned in my post.`

Comment: Just noticed that you're overwriting your outer `$ret` with other query results.

Comment: @apokryfos You're correct. That fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're reusing the variable `$ret`. You should have a different return variable for the SELECT statment and UPDATEs. In the second loop you're trying to do a `fetchArray()` of the return of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Result::lastErrorMsg() in`

Comment: sorry I meant `print_r($db->lastErrorMsg()); die();`

Comment: If I uncomment out the echo'd string in my while statement, it appears it gets through a single iteration and then throws the error mentioned in my post.

Comment: Ahh.. yes because you're reusing the variable `$ret`. You should have a different return variable for the SELECT statment and UPDATEs. In the second loop you're trying to do a `fetchArray()` of the return of an UPDATE statement.